# How would I change the database of a running teamcity?

Tags: teamcity

My Teamcity is installed on a AWS EC2 server and even the database is there.
I want to move the Teamcity database to RDS, how would I change the database of a running teamcity?

Answer (score 9):

if you already have a database with teamcity data elsewhere:

1. shutdown TC server
2. modify /config/database.properties to point at new db
3. restart server

otherwise you will need to migrate the current database into a new empty database following the instructions at https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Migrating+to+an+External+Database